# How do I assign colors to containers from a list of colors?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

**How do I assign colors to my row from a list of colors**
Here is the code.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Rows and Columns Matrix'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Color> manyColors = [
      Colors.red,
      Colors.green,
      Colors.blue,
      Colors.yellow,
      Colors.brown,
      Colors.purple,
      Colors.orange,
      Colors.pink
    ];


    List<Widget> myRowChildren = [];
    List<List<int>> numbers = [];
    List<int> columnNumbers = [];
    int z = 1;
    int numberOfTubes = 18;
    Color concol = Colors.red;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTubes; i++) {
      int fibersPerTube = 24;
      for (int y = 0; y < fibersPerTube; y++) {
        int currentNumber = z + y;
        columnNumbers.add(currentNumber);
      }
      z += fibersPerTube;

      numbers.add(columnNumbers);
      columnNumbers = [];
    }

    myRowChildren = numbers
        .map(
          (columns) => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: columns.map((nr) {


              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: manyColors[0],
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1,
                    )),
                child: Text(
                  nr.toString(),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: myRowChildren,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to assign first row, the first color from the list, second row second color from list and so on.
[I want to achieve this chart's functionality in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3DiD.png)
This is basically a chart for color coding of optical fiber color coding. I will add a row at the top of my matrix which will have column names for each and every column of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` of the list to choose the color from the color's list. In `.map()` method you don't get access to the `index` so instead use `.asMap()`. like this:

```
    numbers
        .asMap().forEach(
          (index, columns) => myRowChildren.add(Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: columns.map((nr) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: manyColors[index],
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
```

Comment: I've tried this but it is showing this error in the console
lib/main.dart:84:37: Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
    myRowChildren = numbers.asMap().forEach(
it says .forEach has a type of void so its value can't be used.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I have edited the solution now. Instead of assigning numbers to `myRowChildren` you can add widgets to it that we get from `forEach()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please tell me one more thing. How can I take the values of all the colors from the user and pass it into my chart? and how do I show only one container like user only wants to find the color of 45. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can create a form to take the color values from the user. Create a variable `columnNumber` and update its value according to the user and show the column of the same number. When user enters another value then call `setState()`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are setting the color of the containers to the first color in the array.

```dart
color: manyColors[0],
```

You get a unique number for each container as the variable `columns` inside the map. All you had to do was map the unique number to the required index of the color array.

```dart
color: manyColors[(columns % manyColors.lenght)],
```

Comment: color: manyColors[(nr -1) % manyColors.length],

Comment: this worked for me.